# Firebase data for all users without authorizing

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is it possible to create some parts of data available for users like list of shop products without authorizing but only authorized users can change the information about products or create new ones?

Comment: Your question is both extremely vague and extremely unclear.

Comment: @DuncanC I think question is clear, he want shopping products accessable to all but only authorized users can actually change/add cart

Comment: That's actually what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it, just declare following rules at that specific location

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Products":{
      ".read": "true",
    ".write": "auth.uid!=null"
    }

  }
}
```

only authurized users can write data.

Comment: So I can define rules for every path? I understand that "Products" are one of these paths.

Comment: yes you can define on any path depends on your structure. please go through this link once https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. In the security rules of your Firebase database you can specify different rules for `.read` and `.write`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "auth !== null"
  }
}
```

The rules above allow anyone to read anything in the database, but only logged in users can write to it.